# Set django combo box options to colors?

Tags: python, css, django, pinax

Subjects says it all pretty much. I want the user to be able to choose the background of their profile. I want them to be able to choose from a few generic colors in a combo box or type in their own hex code in a box below. So my question is... can I set each option in a combo box to a color instead of a word? Thanks!

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (u'Red', *a rectangle of red*),
        (u'Orange', *a rectangle of orange*),
        (u'Yellow', *a rectangle of yello*),
        (u'Green', *a rectangle of green*),
        (u'Blue', *a rectangle of blue*),
        (u'Purple', *a rectangle of purple*),
    )
    bgcolor = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) that displays colors based on the value for the entry, then assign the widget in the form.